# Should not i use any relative measurement for any element if i need fixed width, pixel perfect design?

Tags: css, xhtml, cross-browser

Should not i use any relative measurement in css for any element if i need fixed width, pixel perfect design?

would it be better to use `px` always?

Comment: I make no attempt to answer the question because I never think in those terms, just pointing out that when I increase my browser's font size because I can't read your tiny text your "pixel perfect" design is going to fall apart. "Pixel perfect" is, IMHO, a misguided attempt to impose the *inflexibility* of print media onto an otherwise flexible web page.

Comment: but many client needs pixel=perfect design. and these days all browser scale in `px` also. Are you using IE6?

Comment: Why does your client demand pixel-perfect design? Have you explained the benefits of relative size design to them?

Comment: client doesn't say about using `em` or `px` then just math pixel perfection of design with PSD mockup. Client say in defaul font-size condition. website should should be identical to PSD.

Comment: > Client say in defaul font-size condition. website should should be identical to PSD. <

That will never happen. My default font-size in my browser is different than the out-of-the-box default size. My browser window is taller and narrower than yours is (and _never_ maximized)
It is part of a web designers job (IMO) to explain this so clients understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a pixel-perfect design (which is a silly goal) then definitely use pixels for the sizing of all elements - i.e. width, height, margin, padding. That's what most developers do anyway.

However you will never get a pixel-perfect design where fonts are concerned. Different operating systems have different fonts and there will always be minor cross-browser differences. So you can use either px or em for font sizes, whatever is easiest in your situation.

Comment: you mean if i use Arial 12 PX font then it will look different in various browser and operating systems

Comment: Correct - because my computer doesn't even have Arial so it will use a different sans-serif font.

Answer (score 1):

While pixel perfect is a noble goal, it's also a nearly impossible one, for the reasons listed above, like font rendering on different browsers and different operating systems. If you want to use EMs, but still have a layout you can easily size, here's an easy way to do that:

```
body {
  font-size: 62.5%; /* 1 EM now equals 10px */
}
```

Browsers (generally) have 16px as their default text size. setting the body font-size to 62.5% brings that down to 10px, which is much easier to calculate. If you want an  tag to be 14px, you'd write:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 140%;
  /* OR */ font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

Either one will work and go a long way toward achieving your goal of pixel perfect, but still give you some flexibility.